# Can't locate CSS in a wordpress. Are there people here who understands WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am working on a website that uses a Divi child theme.
There are styles that change the colors of the buttons.
I need to find and change them.
I don't see where they are in the inspect.
And I can found them in the theme editor style.css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGLIP.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In DIVI Theme buttons have his own settings and from there you can manage that CSS for that particular button like: https://prnt.sc/1rp0x71

Please check hope this will help to you for edits button styles

Comment: Yes, I know, but this code overrides the style that I set in the diva editor.